# How can I kill the fat Heartless?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

There are heartless that are essentially big fat spheres with arms and legs and a teeny head.

I find these guys hard to kill, because I am a button masher and I just sorta hack at their bellies with my keyblade.

Is there a faster way to kill these guys? Or do they just die slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of enemy is called a Large Body. The weak spots for these Heartless are their backs, where they take increased damage. You need to maneuver yourself around them and hit them from behind, though you can also jump up and hit their heads as well. Basically, you want to stay mobile when you fight them, especially because of their charge attack, which can knock you backwards and do a decent bit of damage.

As you've seen, they can also take damage when you hit them from the front, but it takes much longer to kill them. Dodging when they charge is helpful because there is a short moment where they pause afterwards, which gives you the chance to smack them about a bit.

Comment: Ah so poking them in the belly isn't entirely useful. That explains SO much.